# While Saving the excel using workbook.saveAs getting the Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC?

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2, excel-2013

I have problem in my project.I want to write data into exist excel file in Asp.NET C# on Windows 2008 server . I created project on my local computer and it is working properly but When I published on server I get this error:
The Error

```
:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): 
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs(Object Filename,Object FileFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended, Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, Object AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local) 
at Stock.EService.ReadExistingExcel()
```

Here is save file code:

```
mWorkBook.SaveAs(path3, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true,Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

mWorkBook.Close(true, Missing.Value,Missing.Value);
```

How can solve my problem.I create a file in server and gave full control but my project does not work.
Please help me.

Comment: Using Office Interop in a Windows Service (IIS is a Windows Service) is asking for trouble, unsupported and unable to be licensed. Use a library to read and write Excel files.

Comment: @CodeCaster do you know any example supported by IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused by the difference of Excel version between your local machine and the server.

Comment: my local machine 2010 version and server 2013 version .may it be problem?

Comment: I think this problem did not come from different version.

Comment: Does "Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal" allows macro in the file? Edit: I found "xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled" should.

Comment: I saw `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This problem plagued me for quite a while. I had Excel 14.0 in the dev environment and Excel 15.0 in the production environment.

Here are a list of most things I tried to resolve the issue, however please keep in mind that it may have been one, all, or a combination of these things that resolved it for me.

1. Start -> Run -> lusrmgr.msc -> Add service account to Administrators group.
2. Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> Properties -> COM Security -> Add user to all permissions.
3. Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application -> Properties -> Security -> Add user to all permissions.
4. Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Windows Management and Instrumentation -> Properties -> Security -> Add user to all permissions.
5. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Protected View -> Uncheck all 3 boxes.
6. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> ActiveX Settings -> Enable all controls & uncheck safe mode.
7. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Macro Settings -> Enable all macros -> Trust access to the VBA project object model.
8. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> File Block Settings -> Select Open selected file types in Protected View.
9. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> File Block Settings -> Uncheck everything.
10. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> External Content -> Enable all Data Connections; Enable automatic update for all Workbook links.
11. Excel -> File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trusted Locations -> Check Allow Trusted Locations + Add C:\ and any UNC paths + subdirectories.
12. Excel -> File -> Options -> Advanced -> Check "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)"
13. In code, instead of using .SaveCopyAs, use .SaveAs with Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault for xlsx files and Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled for macro-enabled workbooks.